# 16.04 did not find the wireless device

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I'm facing the wireless device problem. After installation the Ubuntu 16.04 brand new. I can't use wireless.

[image]

This is what I tried.
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Adding a text description of what you have done and the output (any errors) would make it easier to follow the problem you're having.  Some usefulness would be easier for me to copy text from your output and perform searches for similar problems and resolutions.  The screen shots are alright, but should be in addition to the actual text.